# How to batch process with hibernate scroll ScrollableResults?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, scroll, batch-processing

Let say you already configure hibernate batch-size to support batch operations.

```
    blPU.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
```

Then how to write block of code to process batch?

Answer (score 1):

```
    int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;
    DynamicDaoHelper dynamicDaoHelper = new DynamicDaoHelperImpl();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = dynamicDaoHelper.getSessionFactory((HibernateEntityManager) em);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.openTransaction();
    // must use HQL query so that scroll.get(0) returns entity.
    // if use native SQL, scroll.get() returns row object.
    org.hibernate.Query q = session.createQuery(" SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.isProcessed = false");
    ScrollableResults scroll = q.setCacheable(false).setFetchSize(100).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
boolean hasNext = scroll.next();
    try {
         List<Product> batchProduct = new ArrayList<Product>(BATCH_SIZE);
         while (hasNext) {
             batchProduct.clear();
             int count = 0;

             // get a batch of products, quantity should be same as BATCH_SIZE
             while (hasNext) {
                Product product = (Product) scroll.get(0);
                batchProduct.add(product);
                count++;
                hasNext = scroll.next();
                if (count % BATCH_SIZE == 0 || !hasNext)
                   break;
             }

             // process batch
             processBatch(batchProduct);

             // persist batch and release memory
             session.flush();
             session.clear();
         }
    } finally {
        scroll.close();
    }
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
```

Notes: call scroll.next() will cause checking existence and move to next record, should use boolean flag to call next() once only.